# Laravel route with parameter causes 404

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a route setup which is throwing a 404 in my Laravel 5.6 app.

The problematic route is:

`Route::get('/project/{project_id}/issue/create', 'IssueController@create');`

If I remove the `{project_id}` parameter the view loads..but I need to be able to pass this id since I will be using it on this view to create new issues that are assigned to a project. All of the other routes work without issue.

My routes file (web.php) looks like this:

```
Route::get('/projects', 'ProjectController@index');
Route::get('/project/{project_id}', 'ProjectController@show');
Route::get('/project/{project_id}/issue/{issue_id}', 'IssueController@show');
Route::get('/project/{project_id}/issue/create', 'IssueController@create');
```

And my create function in the IssueController file is this:

```
public function create()
{
    return view('issue.create');
}
```

Comment: placing $project_id as an argument in create method should suffice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed project_id as parameter of your create method. Try this:

```
public function create($project_id)
{
    return view('issue.create');
}
```

and make a route like this:

```
Route::get('/project/issue/create/{project_id}','IssueController@create');
```

Comment: This is great, and works but wondering can you explain why my original route won't work by just adding the parameter into the create method?

Comment: Reading the documentation i assume that you cannot pass parameters to a controller method using your kind of notation. To use your url notation, you have to call a controller method manually from a explicit call of method. My english is terrible, but laravel have a awesome documentation page with the solution to your problem:
[link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/routing#route-parameters) - see the second code sample of the section. Sorry for the day delay.